# Как сделать редирект http и www и скрыть папки в url и расширение файлов?

Tags: url, редирект

Есть следующая структура

```
/pages/yslugi.php
/pages/
/
```

Xочу сделать редиректы с `www` и `https`, убрать в URL расширение файлов в конце, при этом не должен открывать путь с расширением.
Пример: https://site.ru/yslugi, но https://site.ru/yslugi.php должно средиректить или не найтись и убрать из URL папку `pages`.

Вроде задачка несложная, я нашел решения по отдельности

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

но все вместе это не работает, еще на закрытие путей с расширением не нашел решения
(нашел вариант когда работают оба варианта).

Если есть у когото решение данного вопроса, то буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

не помогло, но близко

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[^?]+\.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$       [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.      [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(\.php|$) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.php [L]
```